# Zend Framework - how to use in view script variables declared in other controller?

Tags: zend-framework, variables, view, controller

Zend Framework - how to use in view script variables  declared in other controller?
Do I need to pass the variable to view in the controller again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **yes!**, you have to reassign the data to the view.

However there are options.

If this data is going to be used in many view scripts it may be appropriate to build a [view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html) or an [action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) depending on your use case.

A simple View helper:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Length extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{

    public function length($minutes)
    {

        $hours = floor($minutes / 60);
        $minutes = $minutes % 60;

        if ($hours > 0) {
            $time = sprintf("%01d Hours %02d Minutes", $hours, $minutes);
        } else {
            $time = sprintf("%02d Minutes", $minutes);
        }
        return $time;
    }
}
```

a simple action helper:

```
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_Login extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{

    public function direct()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Login();
        $form->setAction('/index/login');

        return $form;
    }
}
```

If your data is to be used in multiple actions a single controller you can set the data in the init() method:

```
public function init()
    {
        //initialize the flash messenger action helper to work in all actions
        if ($this->_helper->FlashMessenger->hasMessages()) {
            $this->view->messages = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger->getMessages();
        }
    }
```

If you simply need to save a piece of data for a short period of time you can save it to the [registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.registry.using.html) or for a longer period you can use the [session](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html) (I find this solution particularly useful).

These are just some of the more common ways to make different pieces of data available to the application. A more directed question would likely receive more directed answers.

Answer (score 0):

ex: If you have 2 controllers  :

Controller A : It has some variable and variable will be pass to the view A
Controller B : It has some variable and variable will be pass to the view B

The view B can't access to the variable of the controller A.

So if you want to use variables of controller A in view B you have to redeclared it in Controller B

Answer (score -1):

If you have some 'core' view variables that you want to add to multiple view instances then you could conceivably have an additional layer of abstraction and declare your core view variables in there. For instance:

```
class myController extends Zend_Controller_Action
```

could become

```
class myController extends myCoreController
```

and

```
class mySecondController extends myCoreController
```

and

```
class myCoreController extends Zend_Controller_Action
```

In this way you can have your core variables available across controllers and maintain them all in one place.

Comment: Extending Zend_Controller_Action in this way would be extremely bad form and is almost never required.

Comment: I don't agree with you Rocky. If you have a core framework that you wish to deploy across multiple site instances it is kind of vital to extend and add layers of abstraction. Do you know of a better solution to such a core system - I would like to learn if there is a better method.

Comment: I didn't say never, I said almost never. There are always edge cases that exceed the expected use case and require different choices. For most of us, view helpers, action helpers, plugins and init() are a more correct solution.

Comment: Glad you agree I was actually correct as well as you then :) Thanks.